# How to push docker image to ghcr.io organization

Tags: ghcr

I am trying to push images I have built locally to the GitHub Container Registry aka Packages.
I have authenticated GitHub using PAT and authorized access to the organization. Let's name this organization EXAMPLEORG.
used the following command:

```
export CR_PAT=ghp_example_pat ; echo $CR_PAT | sudo docker login ghcr.io -u exampleuser --password-stdin
```

After that, I used the following command to push the image to ghcr.io:

```
docker push ghcr.io/exampleorg/exampleapp:v0.5
```

Unfortunately, I am getting this message after trying to upload image layers:

```
unauthorized: unauthenticated: User cannot be authenticated with the token provided.
```

Does somebody knows what I am missing here?

Followed this guide:
https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry#authenticating-to-the-container-registry

Is there something more I need to do in order to manually push image to Org packages (not interested to do it from the workflow at the moment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it was due to the wrong content of the `~/.docker/config.json` file. During the first command, it happens to fail while writing. So I used `sudo` to circumvent this, and indeed it was circumvented, but the new file is now written in `/root/.docker/config.json` which is not desired outcome. Using `docker login` afterward will not read the config file from the root's home.
The solution to this is not to use `sudo` instead delete `~/.docker/config.json` and then execute:

```
export CR_PAT=ghp_example_pat ; echo $CR_PAT | docker login ghcr.io -u exampleuser --password-stdin
```